# How many parellel connection HTTPClient can make

Tags: java, httpclient

Below is the code which we are using to call Microsoft Dynamics. I want to know how many parallel connection this code can create or how many parallel request it can send.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CredentialsProvider.PROVIDER, new ConsoleAuthPrompter(logger));

    String strURL = getstringURL();
    String strSoapAction = "";
    strSoapAction = getSoapAction();
    PostMethod httppost = new PostMethod(strURL);
    String ContetType = getContentType();
    RequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(getSOAPxml(),"application/json", "utf-8");
    httppost.setRequestEntity(entity);
    httppost.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", strSoapAction);
    httppost.setDoAuthentication(true);

    try {
        // execute the GET
        int status = client.executeMethod(httppost);

        if (httppost.getStatusCode() == 200)
            setReply_SOAPxml(httppost.getResponseBodyAsString());
        else {
            logger.error("Server Replied with Error :"
                    + httppost.getStatusCode() + " "
                    + httppost.getStatusText() + " "
                    + httppost.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw new Exception("Server Replied with Error : ["
                    + httppost.getStatusLine().toString() + "] "
                    + httppost.getStatusCode() + " "
                    + httppost.getStatusText() + " "
                    + httppost.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
    } finally {
        // release any connection resources used by the method
        httppost.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Please tag your question correct. `httpclient` reads **DO NOT USE**. Instead, use one of the suggested alternatives. Whatever corresponds to what you are using.

Comment: 3,17162. Sorry jk. Many factors are involved, and will depend on your vm, host, fd number, etc. as @Zabuza states, you better test it on the destined host